# closing excel file as i close the userform without leaving other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

how can i close an excel file as i close the userform without closing other excel files.

i used this code but it closses all the workbooks that are running.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Unload UserForm1
   Workbooks("ThisWorkbook1").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

How can i fix this code,

Thank you

Comment: Maybe that workbook that you close fires other events that make other workbooks to close

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns i don't think so the workbook1 isn't linked to others in any way

Comment: *i don't think so* is not a good answer. MAke sure it does not. Type `Stop` right before `Unload UserForm1` and execute your code. It will stop in this line and then from there, execute it with F8, line by line, debugging it, so you can see at what exact moment all workbooks close. and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Unload UserForm1
> ```

That's unloading the *default instance* of the form, which may or may not be the instance that's currently running. Avoid referring to `UserFormModuleName` in the form's code-behind: use `Me` instead:

```
Unload Me
```

That said, if you're planning to close the containing workbook just after that, whether you unload the form or not makes little to no difference whatsoever. In fact, I would avoid `Unload` altogether (see [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) I wrote a little while back).

Assuming you mean to close `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the code that contains this VBA code), then use `ThisWorkbook` to qualify the `Workbook.Close` member call:

```
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

That said...

```
Workbooks("ThisWorkbook1").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

That instruction can only ever close one single workbook, if it doesn't blow up with error 9 because there is no `ThisWorkbook1` workbook opened - *your princess is in another castle*, this cannot possibly close *all opened workbooks*.

I would look at the code that's invoking `UserForm1.Show`; if there's code after the `.Show` call that's doing something like `Application.Quit`, then that's why everything is closing: assuming you've shown us all of it, the form's code-behind can't possibly be doing that.

Comment: thank you you were right i had an Application.Quit in the code